# Color some specific trees in a JFace treeviewer

Tags: java, swt, jface

I have to visually differentiate certain nodes and its children in a JFace tree. Due to limitations, I can only extend the label provider.

How can I color the nodes and their children? I'm open to other methods for making the nodes stand out.

```
class ExistingScheduleLabelProvider extends LabelProvider {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        if (element instanceof Schedule) {
            Schedule schedule = (Schedule) element;
            return schedule.getDescription();
        } else if (element instanceof BatchReport) {
            BatchReport report = (BatchReport) element;
            Schedule schedule = (Schedule)report.eContainer();
            return (schedule.getBatchReports().indexOf(report)+1) + " - " + report.getDescription(); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public Image getImage(Object element) {
        if (element instanceof Schedule)
            return SchedulingUIPlugin.getImage(SchedulingImageConstants.IMG_SCHEDULE);
        else if (element instanceof BatchReport)
            return SchedulingUIPlugin.getImage(SchedulingImageConstants.IMG_BATCH_REPORT);
        return super.getImage(element);
    }   

}
```

From the available nodes in the tree, can I color only the nodes which I want based on a condition in order to differentiate them from other nodes?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO! However, questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: HI, I just put down the code here, is it clear, or do you wish to have more clear question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your label provider implements `org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IColorProvider` then it will be asked for the colors for the various elements.

Comment: it doesn't, the class which i extend is labelprovider

Comment: What I am saying is you should also implement IColorProvider in your label provider